# Failure on HttpWebrequest with inner exception Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, vmware, vcenter, system.net.webexception

Using C#, .Net 4.5, I'm trying to send out a web request through HttpWebRequest on a remote server. Please see the code below. 
I tried most of the solutions suggested by some forums but I always end up with the same error. Please see the stack trace below.
The error is thrown when calling the request.GetReponse() method.

Additional info, basically, I'm trying to call the reloadSslCertificate function of vmware's vCenter component installed on a remote server. Currently, the error only happens on vCenter 5.5. It works fine in versions 5.1 and below.

```
        var uri = String.Format("https://{0}/some_url", serverName);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        request.Credentials = credential;
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;


        var response = request.GetResponse();
```

> Exception : System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was
>   closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party
>   has closed the transport stream. at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just want to share that this issue has already been resolved.

I just modified the part of the code where I set the security protocol before issuing the web request.

From:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

To:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

As it turned out, vCenter 5.5 uses TLS as its SSL protocol in its configuration. I hope people may find this helpful when they encounter this same issue.

Comment: Upvoting since this greatly helped me, but for anyone else: also check and see if there are new versions you can append here. For my needs, I was needing Tls12 instead of Tls.

Comment: any comments on what if I get this error while trying to generate code using the CMD?

Answer (score 18):

We ran into the same exception. In our case, the answer was incredibly similar to @Dennis Laping's answer. Another team had setup the service we were trying to hit within a [Rancher](http://rancher.com/) load balancer, which by default did not allow TLS 1.0 or SSL3. It just so happens the current default for [SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) (without setting it) in .NET only allows TLS 1.0 or SSL3.

As soon as we set the [SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows, everything worked fine:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

All that being said, the documentation for [SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) states that:

> Your code should never implicitly depend on using a particular protection level, or on the assumption that a given security level is used by default. If your app depends on the use of a particular security level, you must explicitly specify that level and then check to be sure that it is actually in use on the established connection. Further, your code should be designed to be robust in the face of changes to which protocols are supported, as such changes are often made with little advance notice in order to mitigate emerging threats.

We'll be reevaluating what the best solution is to our protocol situation, but for now I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: +1 for saving my life. In order for our service to receive an A rating on ssllabs, we severely limited the allowed protocols of our endpoint - breaking our client applications. Your answer is what did the trick to fix it! Thanks!!

Comment: any comments on what if I get this error while trying to generate code using the CMD?

Answer (score 1):

See this link, it worked for me:
[How to do HTTPS with TcpClient just like HttpWebRequest does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143010/how-to-do-https-with-tcpclient-just-like-httpwebrequest-does)

```
Dim trust_all_certificates As New CertificateOverride
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf trust_all_certificates.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

Public Class CertificateOverride

    Public Function RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean

        'CertEXPIRED = 2148204801
        'CertVALIDITYPERIODNESTING = 2148204802
        'CertPATHLENCONST = 2148204804
        'CertROLE = 2148204803
        'CertCRITICAL = 2148204805
        'CertPURPOSE = 2148204806
        'CertISSUERCHAINING = 2148204807
        'CertMALFORMED = 2148204808
        'CertUNTRUSTEDROOT = 2148204809
        'CertCHAINING = 2148204810
        'CertREVOKED = 2148204812
        'CertUNTRUSTEDTESTROOT = 2148204813
        'CertREVOCATION_FAILURE = 2148204814
        'CertCN_NO_MATCH = 2148204815
        'CertWRONG_USAGE = 2148204816
        'CertUNTRUSTEDCA = 2148204818

        Return True

    End Function

End Class
```

### P.S.

I inserted this line of code before just to be sure that the certificate from the server side is accepted: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`

Comment: any comments on what if I get this error while trying to generate code using the CMD?

Comment: Zeeshan, can you give us more information? And, I think you should open a new question (if one doesn't exist) because I think that you have been experiencing another type of "error".