# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream exception when getting a response from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-authentication, httpwebresponse

I am calling a third party service and when I ask for a response it throws out an exception that says

> "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream exception".

I think that there is a problem in sending credentials. I have even tried supplying new credentials. Here is the full code

```
string get_url = "https://**.*******.com/com/******/webservices/public_webservice.cfc?wsdl&Method=CreateUser&SiteID=**&WSPassword=******&UserName=******";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(get_url);
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
//request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
//request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*****", "*****");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1";

// Show the sent stream
//lbl_send_stream.Text = send_stream;
//lbl_send_stream.Text = get_url;
// Get UserId And LoginToken From Third Party DB
// ==============================================
//Exception gets throwed When code hits here
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639846/failure-on-httpwebrequest-with-inner-exception-authentication-failed-because-the

Comment: I tried that, It does not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664566/authentication-failed-because-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I found the answer, It was because the third party webservice we were calling did not support TLS 1.0 they supported 1.1 and 1.2. So I had to change the security protocol.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: You can add it before getting the HTTPResponse from request.

Comment: My SecurityProtocolType doesn't show option for Tls12 and Tls11. I am using .net framework 4.

Comment: .Net 4.0 does not know about Tls11 and Tls12.  To access those you need to be using .Net 4.5 or later.

Comment: If using .Net 4.0 you can use a numeric value for TLS1.2 `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

Comment: Also see https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/ for other options and frameworks.

Comment: My app's `Target Framework` was set to .Net Framework 4.5.2 but still I had to place this code to get connected to an Azure API set HTTPS only, TLS1.2

Comment: Interesting. I have WPF app on .NET 4.7.2 that started failling recently without this line. However, when executing same code from console app (also .NET 4.7.2) - no problem.
Anyway, thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: This answer resolved my issue when I encountered the same exception when calling Azure AD secured Function Apps and Web Apis, from a desktop/native app even though the desktop app was created from the quickstart provided by the Azure portal.

Comment: I am using something similar with a FtpWebRequest; if i include a line like this:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13; 
i get this error
"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."
If i don't include that line i get this error instead:
"error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol"

Comment: any comments on what if I get this error while trying to generate code using the CMD?

Comment: I used this solution but using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol before making request and this does not work when using before response

Comment: Tried @ChiragK but it didn't help. Still getting the same error.
System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured in send'
InnerException: IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, initially I changed the security protocol but it didn't work, then I realize that I need to change security protocol before creating the WebRequest:

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fullURL);
        request.Headers = requestHeaders;
        byte[] Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a limitation of using TLS 1.2 only and more than anything else the resource address (URL/address) was local. So above solution didn't work for me. After closely analysing web.config I tried using `<bypasslist>` for local URLs and miracle happened!

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="false" proxyaddress="<yourproxyaddress>" bypassonlocal="true" />
      <bypasslist>  
        <add address="[a-z]+\.abcd\.net\.au$" />  
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Please note I was already using `<proxy>` setting for accessing other external URLs so not having this setup was not allowed either. Hope this helps!

Comment: any comments on what if I get this error while trying to generate code using the CMD?

Comment: Try this:
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
<your command>