# Error adding web reference (WSDL) to class library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

While adding a Web Reference (WSDL) to a Class library application, the below error message pops-up.

> Error Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a send. Authentication failed because the remote
>   party has closed the transport st.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Are you using username&password to add the web reference?

Comment: Can you set TLS settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621686/authentication-failed-because-the-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream-e

Comment: TLS 1.3 Version using
Yes, Username & password using