# Authentication failed during request.GetResponse() in C# using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using C#, .Net framework 4.0 and trying to do HttpWebRequest for Http Basic Authentication and getting below error:

```
Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

I am using below code:

```
string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Error during GetResponse().

I tried all the references in SO:

[Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream exception when getting a response from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621686/authentication-failed-because-the-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream-e)

[Failure on HttpWebrequest with inner exception Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639846/failure-on-httpwebrequest-with-inner-exception-authentication-failed-because-the)

But of no use, still getting same error. Any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved after changing ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol as below:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

As Tls 1.1, 1.2 are not available in .net framework 4.0 directly in System.Net.