# Configured an azure web role for https but it is not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a web role which is configured for 2 endpoints, one http, one https 443:

[image: configuration]

Then I have 3 certs (one is the main and 2 are CA).  I have uploaded all of these and also checked thumbprints are correct.

But when I deploy, the http site works fine but the https site does not.  Fiddler shows:

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream

Any ideas?

Note: Also worth noting this https works fine when on local machine through Visual Studio and only reports the certificate error, which is expected.

Comment: This may be a misconfiguration on the server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143010/how-to-do-https-with-tcpclient-just-like-httpwebrequest-does

Answer (score 0):

First, open the portal and enable RDP to the instances, then connect to the role instance, open IIS, and verify the HTTPS binding is configured properly. Try accessing the site using https locally from the server and verify it works.
Report with the findings.